# Postgres; foreign key reference doesn't work

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a database with a couple of tables which are related, but can't make the code work. This are the statements:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS countries;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS regions;

CREATE TABLE countries (
    country_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
    country_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    country_status BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    country_summary VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    country_image VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (country_id)
);

CREATE TABLE regions (
    region_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
    region_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (region_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_country
        FOREIGN KEY(country_id) 
            REFERENCES countries(country_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I don't get why it just doesn't work, I get the error:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "country_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

Comment: There is no `country_id` column in `regions`.

Comment: @klin rookie mistake, thanks